# Bold the text the last row of dash data-table

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have created a web application in Plotly which amongst other things, displays a range of different DataTables.

Is there a simple way to add conditional formatting to change the last row to bold font?

I basically want to highlight the last row as an average row but do not have anything to reference in a filter, apart the the fact it is the last row of the table.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `style_data_conditional` and `row_index` and do something like this:

```
from dash import Dash
import pandas as pd
from dash_table import DataTable

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "B": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "C": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

app = Dash()

app.layout = DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict("records"),
    columns=[{"name": column, "id": column} for column in df.columns],
    style_data_conditional=[
        {
            "if": {"row_index": len(df) - 1},
            "fontWeight": "bold",
        },
    ],
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

Based on the first example listed in the documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/conditional-formatting)

Comment: Thank you, appreciate my question was vague and included no code. The df was returned as part of a callback, however the bold row was static and always would be the same row_index so I tweeked your solution slightly and used:                         ```style_data_conditional=[{'if': {'filter_query': '{Result} = L', 'column_id': 'Result'}, 'color': red}, {'if': {'filter_query': '{Result} = W', 'column_id': 'Result'}, 'color': 'green'}, {'if': {'row_index': 5}, 'fontWeight': 'bold',}, ],``` Thank you for your help!